# Исключение "нарушение доступа для чтения" в методе std::exchange при возврате значения из функции

Tags: c++

Есть метод `bool DataBase::IsUserFound(User& user)`, который делает проверку на наличие пользователя в базе данных, которая симулируется текстовым файлом. Во время возварата значения возникает исключение "нарушение доступа для чтения" в деструкторе класса `User`, перепробовал все что возможно, не могу понять в чем проблема, код класса `User`и самого метода приведен ниже.

**CPP-файл**

```
User::User(string& name, string& pass, string& codeWord)
{
    _userName = name;
    _password = pass;
    _codeWord = codeWord;
    _counter++;
    _id = _counter;
}
User::User()
{
    _userName = "undefine";
    _password= "undefine";
    _codeWord = "undefine";
    _id = 0;
} 
int User::GetId()
{
    return _id;
}
```

**H-файл**

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class User
{
private:
    string _userName;
    string _password;
    string _codeWord;
    int _id;
    static int _counter;
public:
     User(string& name, string& pass,string& codeWord);
     User();
     int GetId();
};
```

**Метод IsUserFound**

```
bool DataBase::IsUserFound(User& user)
{
    fstream fn;
    fn.open("UsersDBFile.txt", fstream::app|fstream::in | fstream::out);
    User temp;
    while (fn.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(User)))
    {
        if (temp.GetId() == user.GetId())
        {
            fn.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    fn.close();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Такое использование `.read()` годится только для простых типов, например для чисел. Для `string` не годится, потому что у него внутри указатели, которые `read()` прочитает просто как байты из файла. Аналогично `write()`. Вам нужно сначала писать в файл размер строки, потом столько байт из метода `.data()` строки. А при чтении, соотвественно, сначала читать размер строки, делать `resize` на него, потом писать в `.data()` столько-то байт.